# Finding the average of large list of numbers

Tags: algorithm

Came across this interview question.

> Write an algorithm to find the mean(average) of a large list. This
>   list could contain trillions or quadrillions of number. Each number is
>   manageable in hundreds, thousands or millions.

Googling it gave me all `Median of Medians` solutions. How should I approach this problem?
Is divide and conquer enough to deal with trillions of number?
How to deal with the list of the such a large size?

Comment: How about, the same way you find the average of a small list? Add up the numbers and divide by the length of the list. If the numbers are integers no larger than one billion, then the sum won't be any larger than 90 bits.

Comment: It's in C#, but you maybe the algorithmic part will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895396/how-do-i-find-the-average-in-a-large-set-of-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of the list is computable, it's really just a matter of how much memory you have available, how long it's supposed to take and how simple the algorithm is supposed to be.
Basically, you can just add everything up and divide by the size.
If you don't have enough memory, dividing first might work (Note that you will probably lose some precision that way).

Another approach would be to recursively split the list into 2 halves and calculating the mean of the sublists' means. Your recursion termination condition is a list size of 1, in which case the mean is simply the only element of the list. If you encounter a list of odd size, make either the first or second sublist longer, this is pretty much arbitrary and doesn't even have to be consistent.

If, however, you list is so giant that its size can't be computed, there's no way to split it into 2 sublists. In that case, the recursive approach works pretty much the other way around. Instead of splitting into 2 lists with `n/2` elements, you split into `n/2` lists with 2 elements (or rather, calculate their mean immediately). So basically, you calculate the mean of elements 1 and 2, that becomes you new element 1. the mean of 3 and 4 is your new second element, and so on. Then apply the same algorithm to the new list until only 1 element remains. If you encounter a list of odd size, either add an element at the end or ignore the last one. If you add one, you should try to get as close as possible to your expected mean.
While this won't calculate the mean mathematically exactly, for lists of that size, it will be sufficiently close. This is pretty much a `mean of means` approach. You could also go the `median of medians` route, in which case you select the median of sublists recursively. The same principles apply, but you will generally want to get an odd number.
You could even combine the approaches and calculate the mean if your list is of even size and the median if it's of odd size. Doing this over many recursion steps will generate a pretty accurate result.

Comment: That is, assuming you don't want to sample. That's of course another way, just ignore a bunch of values and only use some of them. Ideally pick them at random, which might be the problem here.

Comment: Also, you should note that because of all those recursion steps and the generally time consuming operations, this will take an insane amount of time. If that's an issue, you should probably sample.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is an interview question.  The problem as stated would not arise in practice.  Also, the question as stated here is imprecise.  That is probably deliberate.  (They want to see how you deal with solving an imprecisely specified problem.)

> Write an algorithm to find the mean(average) of a large list.

- The word "find" is rubbery.  It could mean calculate (to some precision) or it could mean estimate.
- The phrase "large list" is rubbery.  If could mean a list or array data structure in memory, or the "list" could be the result of a database query, the contents of a file or files.
- There is no mention of the hardware constraints on the system where this will be implemented.

---

So the first thing >>I<< would do would be to try to narrow the scope by asking some questions of the interviewer.

But assuming that you can't, then a complete answer would need to cover the following points:

- The dataset probably won't fit in memory at the same time.  (But if it does, then that is good.)
- Calculating the average of `N` numbers is `O(N)` if you do it serially.  For N this size, it could be an intractable problem.
- An alternative is to split into sublists of equals size and calculate the averages, and the average of the averages.  In theory, this gives you `O(N/P)` where `P` is the number of partitions. The parallelism could be implemented with multiple threads, with multiple processes on the same machine, or distributed.
- In practice, the limiting factors are going to be computational, memory and/or I/O bandwidth.  A parallel solution will be effective if you can address these limits.  For example, you need to balance the problem of each "worker" having uncontended access to its "sublist" versus the problem of making copies of the data so that that can happen.
- If the list is represented in a way that allows sampling, then you can estimate the average without looking at the entire dataset.  In fact, this could be `O(C)` depending on how you sample.  But there is a risk that your sample will be unrepresentative, and the average will be too inaccurate.
- In all cases doing calculations, you need to guard against (integer) overflow and (floating point) rounding errors.  Especially while calculating the sums.
- It would be worthwhile discussing how you would solve this with a "big data" platform (e.g. Hadoop) and the limitations of that approach (e.g. time taken to load up the data ...)